# Integration of density function of x+y

Tags: probability

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxQvh.jpg 
I don't understand how $$ \int_0^1 f_x(a-y)dy $$ equals to $$  \int_0^a dy $$
Also how you know to integrate from a-1 to 2 equals to 1< a < 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $X,Y$ are independent random variables with densities
$f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ then $X+Y$ has density $f_{X+Y}\left(a\right)=\int f_{X}\left(a-y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy$.
In the special case where $f=f_{X}=f_{Y}$ defined by $a\mapsto1$
if $a\in\left[0,1\right]$ and $a\mapsto0$ otherwise. This leads
to $f_{X+Y}\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(a-y\right)dy$.

Note that $f\left(a-y\right)=1$ if $a-1\leq y\leq a$ and that $f\left(a-y\right)=0$
otherwise.

Next to that there is the restriction $0\leq y\leq1$ and we must
check the cases:

$0\leq a\leq1$ leading to: $0\leq y\leq a$ and to $f_{X+Y}\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(a-y\right)dy=\int_{1}^{a}dy=a$.

$1\leq a\leq2$ leading to: $a-1\leq y\leq1$ and to $f_{X+Y}\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(a-y\right)dy=\int_{a-1}^{1}dy=2-a$.

For other values of $a$ the density of $X+Y$ equals $0$.